# What's the difference between using a div and canvas element for a three.js scene?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I had read that three.js needs the HTML5 `<canvas>` element. However, I can perfectly make a simple `<div>` work giving it height and width properties and then adding the `WebGLRenderer.domElement` as it's child in the HTML hierarchy. It strangely doesn't work if I use a `<canvas>` instead of the `<div>`, as the scene stays all black.

What's the difference in using one or the other? How should the approach differ in each case?

My theory is that `<div>` elements can work as canvas if a size is set and also grants all of the advantages a  element has, but the browser still needs to support the HTML5 `<canvas>` element in order to work properly, but I'd like to have this confirmed by someone with more knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways. Either you append the renderer's DOM element (which is a `<canvas>` element) to another DOM element which is what you did (if you look inside the `<div>` you will find the `<canvas>`), or you put a reference to an already existing `<canvas>` in the renderer's constructor:

`renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: document.querySelector('canvas') })`

In both cases you will have a `<canvas>` element in your DOM during runtime. The only difference is that with the first approach you append it to the DOM from inside your script, while with the second approach you predefine it in HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

Three.js renders using a canvas element automatically. If you have access to your developer tools, you'll see it there sandwiched between the body tags. There's no need to include a div element or a canvas element.

Comment: You need to specify an element to put the render child of if you want it to appear in a specific section of the page though. What you say may be true if you want it fullscreen.